# data.table - merge - duplicates despite all.x = TRUE in R

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

Please correct me if i am wrong, but i thought that by using `all.x = TRUE`, one cannot obtain mote rows than are present in `x`. I have done a very simple merge `command`:

```
basis <<- merge(client[, c("clientID")],
                          claimsClientTotal[, c("clientID")],
                          by = "clientID", all.x = TRUE)
```

However, there are more rows in thee merged `data.table` than in the `x` - here `client`. 
Additionally, the number of duplicates is only `43`

```
> nrow(client)
[1] 194671
> anyDuplicated(client)
[1] 0
> 
> basis <- merge(client[, c("clientID")],
+                           claimsClientTotal[, c("clientID")],
+                           by = "clientID", all.x = TRUE)
> nrow(basis)
[1] 216764
> anyDuplicated(basis)
[1] 43
```

How is it possible that the number of rows on the merged data.table is larger than on the original, while using `all.x = TRUE`?

Also, how come that there are only 43 duplicates, but the difference in row is more tha n 43?

am i missing something ?

Comment: but then why does ´anyDuplicated` not match the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `anyDuplicated` returns the index position of the first duplicate

```
v2 <- c(1:100, 100)
anyDuplicated(v2)
#[1] 101
```

It is just a way to check if there are any duplicates for the vector or data.frame/matrix

If we need to get the number of duplicates

```
sum(duplicated(v2))
#[1] 1
```

---

If we need to get the duplicate rows only

```
basis[duplicated(basis),]
```

Or to return all the duplicates

```
basis[duplicated(basis)|duplicated(basis, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

Comment: How can i print all the duplicates?

Comment: although, i am still unsure how the duplicates get there?

Comment: @Danka You are merging by 'clientID'.  if that is not unique in both the datassets, it can result in duplication

Comment: @Danka Can you check `table(client$clientID)` and `table( claimsClientTotal$clientID)`